# What situations does a Monostate pattern model?

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns

I know what both a Singleton or a Monostate are and how to implement them. Although I can see many uses for a Singleton, I can't imagine a situation where I would want to let the user create as many instances of my class although in reality only one really exists behind the scenes.

Can anybody help me here? I know that for several reasons one should stay away from both patterns, but in theory, what kind of problems does the Monostate model?

Thanks

Comment: Never heard of the monostate pattern. However, I imagine it can be used for a shared ressource of some kind like the Singleton. The link below seems to offer a good example while avoiding a more complex pattern such as an Observer:
http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/16361

Comment: See also http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MonostatePattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monostate, to my eyes, is not a pattern you're likely to implement at an application level, but can be useful at an infrastructure level.  [This comment on Alex Martelli's presentation of the pattern in Python](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531/#c9) provides an illustrative example.

Consider a DCOM or .NET remoting scenario, where we have an object on the server representing a Person named Bob.  Bob is not a singleton, because Bob is not the only Person.  But several clients may be talking to Bob at the same time.  In each case, the client does not have a direct reference to Bob (who is in a different address space or on a different machine), but instead has a proxy object.  And that proxy object is local to that particular client.

So we have multiple proxy objects, each with different *identity*, but each proxying the state and behaviour of Bob the server object -- and therefore sharing state and behaviour.  If client Alice updates Bob's state (by calling a method on her proxy object), then client Carol will see changes in Bob's behaviour (when she calls methods on her proxy object).  Alice and Carol's proxy objects do *not* have the same object identity, but *do* have the same state and behaviour: both represent Bob.  The two proxies exhibit the Monostate pattern.

([The whole thread](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531/) is worth reading for a more detailed discussion, but the above for me was where it clicked into focus.)

Comment: Just the kind of answer I was looking for!